# How to redirect from a URL with location.hash to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js

I recently moved a section of one of my webpages, suppose: `dummy.com/get-started/#setup` out and made it its own page: `dummy.com/setup`. I then deleted the `/get-started` page on my website.

A lot of people have bookmarks to the section saved in their browsers. I don't want their bookmarks to break and want them to be smoothly redirected to the new page.

The catch is that `window.location.hash` is not sent to the server, so I cannot handle the redirect on the server side.

I don't want people to first see a 404 page and then be redirected to the correct page.

Is there a way to send `location.hash` to the server so I would be able to do the redirect on server-side instead of first showing a 404 and then redirecting them to the correct page on client side?

I am using Next.js on my website.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions here,

Solution#1: Use the next.config to set up rewrite rules (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

Solution#2: Implement a middleware to handle the re-write (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware)